# Observable doesn't receives events

Tags: ios, observable, rx-swift, object-lifetime, combinelatest

My code looks like this:

```
 private let myPublishSubject = PublishSubject<Bool>()

 func method(input: String) -> String {
     if input == something {
         myPublishSubject.onNext(true)
         return update(input)
     }
     myPublishSubject.onNext(false)
     return input
 }

 // Output
 let driver: Driver<String>

 init() {
     let myObservable = Observable.just("a")
     driver = Observable.combineLatest(myObservable, myPublishSubject)
         .map { 
...
         }
         .asDriver()
 }
```

Now, in debug, I figured out that `driver` only subscribed and disposed of. when `method` called afterward, there isn't any subscriber to `myPublishSubject.onNext`.
How can I fix it?

Comment: `PublishSubject` streams the event as soon as it get without waiting for any subscriber. So when the event is triggered and the Driver was not subscribed you will lose that event. Check out the RxMarble diagram for more info:- http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aks yesterday answered it correctly: `PublishSubject` streams the event as soon as it gets without waiting for any subscriber. So when the event is triggered and the Driver was not subscribed I lost that event.
Therefore I used `BehaviorRelay` instead, and it solved my problem When subscribing to `BehaviorRelay`, you get the last stream even if the event happen before subscriber was created.